# Can I migrate and update a sqlite database for a flask app running as an Azure Web App?

Tags: python, azure, sqlite, flask

I have deployed a reasonably simple flask app as an Azure Web App. I have opted to have the deployment of updates controlled by a Github branch.

As the app requires little data management, I have used a sqlite database.

I have updated the database since the original deployment and so need to complete a flask db migrate on the SQLite database.

Can I perform a sqlite database update on Azure and if so how?

I have tried logging into the ssh shell for the web app via the Azure portal, moving to the wwwroot directory and trying to do a flask db update, but flask-migrate is not installed so flask db is not recognised (even though it is in the requirements.txt file)

Comment: any update this one

Comment: @sahasrara62 I didn't manage to resolve the issue and quickly moved on to another database engine rather than pin down the exact procedure for this.